# Set Search Property Value to a Variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have a control which is a TreeView node that will always be set to the name of the PC you're currently running the tested software on. Therefore I need the Search Property for the control's Name property to be set to `Environment.MachineName like so:

[image]

The problem with this is that inside `UIMap.Designer.cs` I can see the generated code that this makes and it's trying to use `Environment.MachineName` as a string:

```
this.SearchProperties[WinTreeItem.PropertyNames.Name] = "Environment.MachineName";
```

Obviously this approach won't work, and it's not possible to manually edit `UIMap.Designer.cs` to change this. How can I make this work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is to use the UI Map editor to remove that search item. This should be possible from the window shown in the question. Then, in the test method that needs to do the search, add a statement something like

```
this.uimap.controlNames.SearchProperties[WinTreeItem.PropertyNames.Name]
    = Environment.MachineName;
```

or

```
this.uimap.controlNames.SearchProperties.Add(name, Environment.MachineName;
```

The precise statement depends on the structure of the controls, so where I wrote `.controlNames.` it may need a series of dot-separated control names.

Comment: This is great, thanks! What is the difference between the two syntaxs?

Comment: Not much, personal preference!

Comment: The assignment style relies on already defined attributes of controls and properties. The `Add()` method takes two strings and so allows a wider range of property names.